# Google Maps change title of location

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

I'm implementing a Google Map with the destination of a company on a website. I'm doing it this way with iframe:

```
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=55.670578,12.439694&z=14&output=embed"
```

This is fine but it gives me this output:

[image: Google Map Title]

Can I add a title as a parameter so I won't get the LatLng as the title of my location? The company I'm refering to is not found on Google Maps by searching for its name BTW. So i need to pass this as a parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately what you wanted to do is not possible. There is no parameter that you can use to change the title of that place as it only reflects what is in your "q" parameter.  
As an alternative solution you can try Google Javascript API and check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows